# How to download a file in my app from a cloud with a content URI

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to download a (zip) file from my cloud storage to my app using an intent. I succeeded to access to my cloud with :

```
        var activity = (Activity)Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context;

        // ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is the intent to choose a file via the system's file
        // browser.
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);

        // Filter to only show results that can be "opened", such as a
        // file (as opposed to a list of contacts or timezones)
        intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);

        // Filter to show only images, using the image MIME data type.
        // If one wanted to search for ogg vorbis files, the type would be "audio/ogg".
        // To search for all documents available via installed storage providers,
        // it would be "*/*".
        intent.SetType("*/*");

        activity.StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

and I have my OnActivityResult like this in my Mainactivity.cs :

```
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {

        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 0)
        {

            System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(data.Data.ToString());



            WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
            myWebClient.DownloadFile(uri, "/root"));
        }
    }
```

But I think that my uri adress is not good because it's a content uri but not a file uri. So how I could have a valid file uri from my content uri please ?

Comment: What's your cloud storage? Google drive or something else?

Comment: Currently it's Google drive. I am not using the Google drive api service because I want to have the choice to select the cloud storage in my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using :

System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(data.Data.ToString());

```
            ContentResolver rc = ContentResolver;

            var stream = rc.OpenInputStream(data.Data);

            try
            {
                using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(filepath))
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("exception :" + ex.Message);
            }
```